# How can I make vim-plug recognize a local project?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I am trying to make a plug in for [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug). At the moment I am not sure how to load a local directory. I have ran in my root directory:

```
mkdir vim-test
cd vim-test
git init
mkdir syntax
```

I then went into my `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` file and I have:

```
" Specify a directory for plugins
" - For Neovim: ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged
" - Avoid using standard Vim directory names like 'plugin'
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'junegunn/vim-easy-align'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'cespare/vim-toml'
Plug '~/vim-test'

" Initialize plugin system
call plug#end()
```

Currently, all the other plug ins seem to load, but `vim-test` does not show up as a package when I execute `:PlugInstall` and from what I can tell, it doesn't install either. What am I supposed to do to make `vim-test` show up?

Comment: I *think* PlugInstall is for Github installation. Can you set the `runtime` path to your directory and see if it loads? Check `:help lua` for an example plugin code.

Comment: @Nishant I am not sure exactly what you mean by `runtime` (I am pretty new to Vimscript. But, your first guess was correct (please see my answer for more details). Thanks!

Comment: Please check `:help lua` for an example. Setting `runtime` path to the top-level directory of your project with (i.e a directory with `autoload`, `plugin` etc) works. http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/42.html is there for vim but should be similar for neovim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nishant points out:

> I *think* PlugInstall is for Github installation.

I was able to check the status with `:PlugStatus` and `vim-test` was in fact loaded with a status of `OK`. It just doesn't show up in `:PlugInstall`.